# Difference between ../ and ..// in a file path

Tags: asp.net, relative-path

I am using a relative file path in one of the cs file to get a location to save an image.

Is there any difference in using ../ and ..// for getting the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your slashes are actually backslashes, but in c#, you have to escape backslashes.

```
var path = "..\\file.txt";
```

path's value is actually ..\file.txt, because the "\" is actually one (escaped) backslash.

However, if it is:

```
var path = @"..\file.txt";
```

then it is the same. The @ means you want the string as-is, without any escaping, so both "path" variables are the same.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, and I think MS-DOS and hence Windows follows Unix closely enough here that it is not a difference between the systems, then you can have any number of consecutive slashes at any point in a pathname and it is equivalent to a single slash.  Consequently, your two examples are equivalent.

Note that on Windows, a double slash at the start of a path name indicates a [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNC_path#Uniform_Naming_Convention) - a machine name followed by a path on that machine.